# "À la fin" vs "en fin de compte"

Tags: sens

Is there any difference in meaning between "à la fin" and "en fin de compte"? It seems to me that both mean "in the end" in English. Examples:

- J'ai essayé de l'appeler dix fois, et, à la fin/en fin de compte, il a répondu.
- Ils se sont retrouvés coincés dans un énorme embouteillage. Néanmoins, à la fin / en fin de compte, ils sont arrivés à l'heure.

Comment: Everyone below explains the difference very well. I just want to specify that *à la fin* for *en fin de compte*, *finalement* is a rather obvious anglicism (*in the end*).

Answer (score 2):

They overlap but *en fin de compte* introduces a conclusion, an observation, is closer to *finalement*, *en définitive* (at the end of the day) while *à la fin* is more descriptive and states the precise time some event happened.

I would used either of them in your first example but *en fin de compte* in the second one because when you are *coincé*, you don't move.

Alternatives can be:

> J'ai essayé de l'appeler dix fois et il a fini par répondre.
>
> Ils sont restés coincés dans un énorme embouteillage mais (ils) sont finalement arrivés à l'heure.

Comment: You said that "en fin de compte" introduces a consequence and that it fits better than "à la fin" in the second sentence, but "arriving on time" is *not* a consequence of "being stuck in a traffic jam". An example of consequence would be being late.

Comment: Following OP's comment, I'd vote for replacing *consequence* with *conclusion*. The conclusion being or not consequent.

Comment: @aCOSwt Tha's right, done.

Answer (score 1):

Especially in the first sentence, 'en fin de compte' makes me expect that you will

- introduce an explanation: "J'ai essayé de l'appeler dix fois, et, en fin de compte il n'avait plus de batterie.", or
- act: "J'ai essayé de l'appeler dix fois, et, en fin de compte je suis allé chez lui.".

(The 'Néanmoins' of the second sentence makes this a bit less likely.)

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

**à la fin**: lorsque quelque chose se termine (that's all there is to it, really)

However, "en fin de compte" is more like

> après tout, au bout du compte, tout bien considéré, finalement, en dernière analyse

They are not always interchangeable, there might be a few cases wherein **en fin de compte** can be replaced by **à la fin** and vice-versa.

> J'ai essayé de l'appeler dix fois, et, à la fin/**en fin de compte**, il a répondu.

You repeatedly tried to reach him and thought he would never pick up the damn phone! But he **ultimately/eventually** did. (pardon my French)

> J'ai essayé de l'appeler dix fois, et, **à la fin**/en fin de compte, il a répondu.

**à la fin** is on the last attempt (you would have not tried further). It happened at the end.

> En fin de compte, ça peut nous rapporter gros.

When you think about it, it could actually yield a huge profit. It's also meaning **on the long run**.

> A la fin, ça peut nous rapporter gros.

That's like saying "à la longue" (on the long run). At the beginning maybe not, but ultimately.

Two meanings according to this [link](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/en%20fin%20de%20compte/fr-fr/) and you'll note there is **à la fin** amongst its synonyms. But then again, synonyms are not always interchangeable, it's context dependent.

1. après tout, en dernière analyse.
2. adverbe qui marque l'opposition entre deux choses liées ou entre deux aspects d'une même chose. Cependant, mais, néanmoins, toutefois.